# Convert decimal NCR string to bytes using C#

Tags: c#

I need to allow emojis the be sent in the subject of emails from my application. The user can save the emoji from a web form. When copying and pasting the emoji on the web form, the emoji is saved in a decimal NCR format by the browser.

With the emoji saved in a decimal NCR format, it does not display correctly in the subject line. It is just the decimal NCR string. If I can convert this string to the UTF-8 byte representation, it works just fine.

How can I convert from the decimal NCR format to a UTF-8 byte array? Here is some code that I have been using to test this. I used the [Unicode Code Converter](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/) to get the values for the croissant emoji.

```
        [Fact]
        public void ConvertsToUnicode() {
            // arrange
            var decimalNcr = "&#129360;";
            var bytes      = new byte[] {0xF0, 0x9F, 0xA5, 0x90};
            var emoji      = "";

            // act
            var emojiTest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var encoded   = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emoji);

            // assert
            emojiTest.Should()
                     .Be(emoji);

            encoded.Should()
                   .BeEquivalentTo(bytes);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use

[WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission
>   into a decoded string.

or

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8)

> Converts a string that has been HTML-encoded for HTTP transmission
>   into a decoded string.

**Example**

```
 Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#129360;"));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/edkEmz)